# Full height Column background color with Bootstrap Grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know the chances are slim, but how would you achieve layouts like the following, where left, center and right have different background colors **while using the bootstrap grid system**? I guess the column layout is against the thinking of the Bootstrap grid, am I right?

[image]

**[Here's an online use case url](http://dabblet.com/gist/5326268).**

The CSS is the standard Bootstrap grid CSS for spans etc..

I had a look on some other SO Q and A's but I wouldn't like to use things like JavaScript.. or things not supported by IE7+..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just use this CSS:

```
html, body, .container-fluid, .row-fluid, .blue, .lightgrey {height:100%;}
```

http://dabblet.com/gist/5326320

Comment: the thing is this solution changes the basic grid classes (row-fluid,container-fluid) so it will affect all other pages...

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos your question didn't say it was for just specific pages, but you can just include that css for those pages only then.

Comment: If I needed this layout for many pages I wouldn't be using a grid system like that :-)

Answer (score 6):

The solution from @Omega looks good, here's another option: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/u5XGL/

The important bit of the CSS here is how to get the background colours for columns with varying content height.

I've added a large padding and an equally large negative margin to each column, then wrapped the entire row in in a class with overflow hidden.

**CSS**

```
.col{
margin-bottom: -99999px;
padding-bottom: 99999px;
background-color:#ffc;
}

.col-wrap{
overflow: hidden; 
}
```

You will find that it resoponds well and is also a good cross-browser solution.

Good luck!

Comment: this can be helpful although it doesn't expand to take all the screen height. but indeed can be useful in similar designs.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't realised you are looking for a sticky footer type solution. Cheers!

Comment: For some reason, accepted answer doesn't work for me. And this one works

Comment: Thanks, I'm pleased you found a solution that worked for you @Shiv. There are now new options like Flexbox which may not be so easy to add to an existing site, but when you can they make for a nice clean solution. https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/